# I want to retrieve datas from firebase in shuffle each time when user login

Tags: java, android

I stored data in the firebase Real-Time database and want to retrieve them in a shuffled manner. For example, i need to give data's in shuffled for every user uses that application and every time when the user refresh the page it gives randomly shuffled values

Answer (score 0):

Create a local list after fetching from the Firebase list.
Then shuffle the list using

```
  Collections.shuffle(mylist, new Random());
```

And then assign a range of values to the user as needed.